# Is there an analytical formula for probablity that one random variable is greater than another?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

As the title indicated, I was wondering if there is an analytical result of $p(X>Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent lognormal-distributed random variables such that $x\sim\mathcal{LN}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $y\sim\mathcal{LN}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$. That is to say, I wanna calculate the probability of the event that $X$ is larger than $Y$.

Comment: I think your title is incorrect: it is not a _conditional_ probability you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea. I edited the title. Thanks.

Comment: Are both variables uncorrelated?

Comment: Yes, independent.

Comment: Exponential Function are monotonic increasing, so the inequality sign is preserved when you transform them back to normal. Then the difference of independent normals again is normally distributed, so you can compute the probability numerically.

Comment: You are very insightful. Now, I know how to calculate it based no your suggestion.